# How to separate data of the same time(hour) in ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I have a step table that contains values ​​obtained over the course of a day. I used this to group several values ​​from the same day:

```
MonitorRecord.where(user_id: id).group_by { |item| item.registered_at.to_date }
```

I did this to calculate the total number of steps for migrating data from multiple users. It's working fine and the answer is a very easy hash to work with.

[Result Hash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9cD2.png)

I need to do the same for a heart rate table, only this time, separating by hour and no longer by day. I need this separate data to calculate an hourly average.

Is it possible to make a request as in the previous example, but now separating the data by time (hour)?

The registered_at field has the following format: 2019-05-31 18:10:57

I need to access all the data and not group it into a single one.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as this will return the data separated by hour and then you can do whatever calculation you need. As this will return you a hash like this {"hour": [rows]}

```
MonitorRecord.where(user_id: id).group_by { |item| item.registered_at.strftime(%H) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked fine for me. The only difference was that I used this format: `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")` to filter the data also by day and time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use `strftime`

```
registerd_at.strftime(%H:%M:%S) // 2019-05-31 18:10:57 => 18:10:57
```